# Solspace User - Allow non-SA to send Key Invite?

Tags: members, solspace-user, groups, super-admin

Does anyone happen to know of a way to allow member groups other than Super Admins to send key invites via User from Solspace?

Their docs state that it's SA only, but I had four separate user groups that need to be able to access this function via the front end while not having CP access, thus they can't be Super Admins.

Anyone else run into this and/or discover a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, we have limited the Key Invite feature to Super Admin's only. If you wanted to adjust this on your own, you would have to modify the code in **mod.user.php** around **line 9310**:

```
/** ----------------------------------------
/** Is the current user logged in?
//  are they an admin? must be admin
/** ----------------------------------------*/

 if ( ee()->session->userdata('member_id') == 0 OR ee()->session->userdata('group_id') != 1)
 {
 return $this->_output_error('general', array(lang('not_authorized')));
 }
```

Comment: Mucho thanks! Also got the answer from your support team, but hadn't had time to update this. You all rock on so many levels.